# Link opens a new website instead of my own

Tags: html

I've made a website and integrated wordpress. But when I click a link from wordpress it opens in a new windows.

It is probably because they are dynamic links but I would love to know how I can open them in on the same page.

My website is: http://www.volunteeringnews.com

If you click a link on the right side (say category) it opens a new website but it has to stay on the current one and open in the main section.

I hope someone can help me out here because I've been having this problem for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

I have copied the generated code from your website. The new window happens because of the `target="_blank"` in the anchor `a` tag. If you can check the widget code/settings you would know if you need to change PHP code or is configurable.

```
<div class="socialmedia-buttons smw_left">
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Volunteering-News/391260697641619" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
<img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.volunteeringnews.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/cutout/32/facebook.png" alt="Follow Us on Facebook" title="Follow Us on Facebook" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade">
</a>
<a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/107875899230242366723/107875899230242366723/posts" rel="publisher" target="_blank">
<img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.volunteeringnews.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/cutout/32/googleplus.png" alt="Follow Us on Google+" title="Follow Us on Google+" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade">
</a>
<a href="https://twitter.com/volunteeringnew" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">
<img width="32" height="32" src="http://www.volunteeringnews.com/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/social-media-widget/images/cutout/32/twitter.png" alt="Follow Us on Twitter" title="Follow Us on Twitter" style="opacity: 0.8; -moz-opacity: 0.8;" class="fade">
</a>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: As per the widget's [page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/social-media-widget/) you can configure it under widget settings. It can be found usually under `appearance->widgets`.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. I can see where you coming from but it is not the social media part that I am talking about. If you go to comments for example and you click it, it will guide you to this link: <a href="http://www.volunteeringnews.com/wordpress/?p=1#comment-1">Hello world!</a>. My goal is that the link wordpress creates will open on my website and not on its own. Thank you again.

Comment: @RoaldVanDerTempel Are you asking the specific division to expand in it's specific place and then display all the content in the same place without going to a new page at all?

Comment: Yes, if you go to any of the menu items, it will open in the middle of the page without refreshing a new page. I want wordpress to do the same. I want it to load inside of my main page.

Comment: @RoaldVanDerTempel - Try [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ajaxify-comments/)

Comment: @ Srihari, Thank you for the tip but that wasn't really what I wanted to do. What I want to do is very simple. If you go to http://www.volunteeringnews.com you can see my blog in the mainC2 div. If you click on "Leave a reply" it will direct you to :http://www.volunteeringnews.com/wordpress/?p=20#respond . But it should just open in my mainC2 div without changing the link. I have tried your ajax option and it works, but only on the wordpress site and not my site. I also tried adding the base code to head and making links relative but I can't figure it out.